# Python Jira Lib - Jira Issues respond only the memory adress

Tags: jira, python-jira

I've tried to connect the Jira Lib with the Jira Server of our Company. The authentication is done via PAT. When I try to search for Issues, I always get the response <JIRA Issue at 123456789>.

```
jira = JIRA('https://jira-server.de', get_server_info= False, token_auth=api_key)
jira.issue('Ticket-6000', fields='summary')
```

I would expect I get the summary of the ticket but instead I get only <JIRA Issue at 2496145270544>